# Segmentation fault on reallocating of memory

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, structure, realloc

I need to make a program for bakery managment, I've done structures and three pointer arrays that must contain pointers for object of these structures. But i can't make function to add new bakery because it needs dynamic memory allocating. I've tried to do this but it throws **`Segmentation Fault`** on realloc. I would be grateful for any advice how to properly reallocate memory for these arrays to add element. Also feel free to make comments about other errors in the code, I'm just learning.

```
typedef struct BakeryType {
    char *name;
} BakeType;

typedef struct Bakerys {
    char *name;
    BakeType *type;
    char *photo;
    float weight;
    int portions;
    float price;
    char *description;
} Bakery;

Bakery *bakeryList[0];
BakeType *bakeTypeList[0];

void addBakery() {
    Bakery new;
    *bakeryList = realloc(*bakeryList, (sizeof(bakeryList)/ sizeof(Bakery))+ 1);//Segmentation Fault
    bakeryList[sizeof(bakeryList)/sizeof(Bakery)]=&new;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: You can't have zero size arrays in C. Is this some gcc dialect? Also for the love of obfuscation, get rid of those macros. Use real functions if needed.

Comment: @Lundin it compiled and ran without warnings with zero sized arrays, i`ve suspected that i cant do that but compiler said nothing so i let it be. If i change array size to 1 problem persists. Ok, will remake macros to function, thanks.

Comment: @Lundin You can have zero-element arrays in C. Try it.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn No you can't, period. Try it yourself with a _C language compliant compiler_. https://godbolt.org/z/W4JFcV

Comment: Yes, if you specify `-pedantic-errors`, you'll get an error. But with default options, compiles just fine with both gcc and clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bakeryList` is a zero-element array of pointers to `Bakery`. It has room for zero pointers.

Yet later you set the first element of this array (`*bakeryList` which is the same as `bakeryList[0]`) to whatever comes back from `realloc`. So you're overwriting something, and it probably goes downhill from there.

I think you want `bakeryList` to just be a pointer to `Bakery`. That's how dynamically-allocated arrays work in C: you define a pointer to the first element and use pointer math (e.g., `bakeryList[5]` or `*(bakeryList + 5)`) to access other elements.

Another issue is your use of `sizeof(bakeryList)`. `sizeof` is an operator that's evaluated by the compiler. It doesn't change at runtime. `sizeof(bakeryList) / sizeof(Bakery)` will evaluate to zero because you defined `bakeryList` as a zero-element array. You need another variable to keep track of how many elements are actually in the array at runtime.

Something like this would work:

```
int bakeryCount = 0;
Bakery *bakeryList = NULL;

void addBakery() {
    // Add one to the array.
    bakeryCount++;
    bakeryList = realloc(bakeryList, bakeryCount * sizeof (Bakery));
    // Create a pointer to the new element at the end of the array.
    Bakery *newBakery = bakeryList + bakeryCount - 1;
    // Set all the fields. Note that they will probably contain
    // garbage so you should set them all.
    newBakery->name = ...
}
```

Comment: Removed assigning, and problem persists. I think that it fails inside realloc because i somehow messed up with setting its size, but i cant fugure out how.

Comment: I updated the answer. This code should work. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: why cant i scan name to this new element like this: `scanf("%s",newBakery->name);` ? It also throws segmentation fault

Comment: "sizeof(bakeryList) / sizeof(Bakery) will evaluate to zero because you defined bakeryList as a zero-element array." This isn't correct, because the C standard doesn't mention what will happen if you define a "zero size array". Rather, it explicitly says that an array cannot have size zero, constraint violation of C11 6.7.6.2/1 "... [ and ] may delimit
an expression... If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
have a value greater than zero." So what the OP's code will do is anyone's guess. Probably it is using GNU C non-standard extensions or such.

Comment: @Lundin With default options both gcc and clang compile a zero-element array and report `sizeof` as zero, exactly what you'd expect. Look, I'm not saying a zero-element array is useful, but it's pretty obvious that `sizeof` zero-element array is zero.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn And neither of those compilers are set in C standard mode by default. What the not-C language does isn't particularly relevant, particularly not when teaching beginners.

Comment: I take note of your belief that gcc and clang by default compile a language that is not C. :-)